# Updating the dependent table based on the primary table

Tags: mysql, database, entity-framework

I am trying to build a table for Multiple Choice Question system where each question has unbounded number of choices to select from(Not a fixed number of choices). These number of choices vary from question to question.I am trying to build a database which stores the question as well as the choices.

```
Table Question
{ // Though just two fields are shown, there are many fields in the table actually
questionId;  
question;  
}

Table Choices{  
choiceId;  
questionId;  
choice;
```

}

One can argue that we can dynamically enter the choice directly into Question Table by having a field but this duplicates the other field data. Like if we have 10 choices for a single Question,then we would have 10 rows in Question table with a lot of duplication. So I have separated the Tables as Question and Choice.

The main problem here. We do not know what the question Id is till the question is actually created. We cannot use the Question Id from the Questions table during entering data into the Choices Table. Any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: each time creating a new question, the question should be inserted first, then you have the id. From that insert new choices normally. When using EF, there should be an entity of type `Question` having a navigation property of type `ICollection<Choice>`, so you can easily add new choices for a newly created Question.

Comment: Once the question is inserted, the DB has the Id but how can I retrieve this Id? Because the questionId is my primary key, I cannot get the Id by querying on other fields..

Comment: do you have a model with entity types like `Question`, `Choice`? What I said in the first sentence is used only when you handle it manually, EF would help you do it more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Your structure would be able to handle the requirement you are looking for. In the table Choices you can use a primary key combining questionID and choiceID so that you can use choideIDs starting from 1 for each of the questions rather than trying to find out which ID the choices start for each question.

As for your problem on not knowing what questionID is generated, assuming your questionID is an auto_increment column, you can use your [last_insert_id](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html) function in whatever programming language you are using to find out what questionID was generated by the last insert. As you will be having multiple entries for the choices, it would be hard for you to do this in a single SQL insert command.

Comment: I think this helps a lot. I was just looking for the Id of last element inserted into the Question Table. I think I should be able to figure out how we can get this Id in the language I am using. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Entity Framework...

You should save Question (Even field "question" is empty) and get ID...

If User Cancels everything just remove that question by ID...

Comment: Once the question is inserted, the DB has the Id but how can I retrieve this Id? Because the questionId is my primary key, I cannot get the Id by querying on other fields.

Comment: What Framework are you using? I think your model should have GETTER with name getYOURMODELNAMEId()